# cal -w does not work

Tags: command-line, calendar

With the standard terminal when I type

```
cal -w
```

I get a usage description indicating that 'cal' did not recognize the '-w'
but the '-w' is described in 'info cal' documentation. Is there a setting that enables this?

Comment: IIRC `-w` only applies to `ncal`

Comment: @steeldriver to be fair, the `-w` option is shown in `man cal` however it seems to only work with the `ncal` command

Comment: @CharlesGreen however the synopsis section shows `w` as an option for `ncal` only I think?

Comment: @steeldriver that is true, in that the man page for `cal` and `ncal` is the same page and it is up to the OP to realize that both commands are discussed and not all options are available to both commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing `cal -w` in the terminal shows extra arguments supported by `cal` and even more extra arguments supported by `ncal`:

```
$ cal -w
Usage: cal [general options] [-hjy] [[month] year]
       cal [general options] [-hj] [-m month] [year]
       ncal [general options] [-bhJjpwySM] [-s country_code] [[month] year]
       ncal [general options] [-bhJeoSM] [year]
General options: [-NC31] [-A months] [-B months]
For debug the highlighting: [-H yyyy-mm-dd] [-d yyyy-mm]
```

- `cal` only supports `h`, `j` and `y` arguments
- `ncal` supports same arguments plus `w` option you seek and many more

Answer (score 4):

**There is no setting to change.**

`cal` and `ncal` share documentation. The -w option is available only for `ncal`

This is explained in the 'usage' error you receive when you try to use -w with `cal`.

If you wish, feel free to file a bug report against the 'bsdmainutils' package with recommended clarification to the documentation.